# Stopping job because the scheduler could not execute a filter. Epson L355 and Ubuntu 18.04 printing problem

Tags: drivers, 18.04, printing, epson

I cannot print anything using epson L355 printer. 
I have laptop and PC. On PC everything works ok, but my laptop cannot print anything, but scanner works.

I have installed the driver:
`epson-inkjet-printer-201207w/now 1.0.0-1lsb3.2 amd64 [installed,local]`

In `/var/log/cups/error_log` I found following logs:

```
E [04/Mar/2020:21:38:58 +0100] L355: Directory \"/opt/epson-inkjet-printer-201207w/cups/lib/filter\" has insecure permissions (040755/uid=1000/gid=1000).
E [04/Mar/2020:21:38:58 +0100] [Job 55] Unable to start filter "/opt/epson-inkjet-printer-201207w/cups/lib/filter/epson_inkjet_printer_filter" - Success.
E [04/Mar/2020:21:38:58 +0100] [Job 55] Stopping job because the scheduler could not execute a filter.
```

Could someone give me a hint how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing this:

Change the ownership of `/opt/epson-inkjet-printer-201207w/cups/lib/filter` files and dirs. You can do it by running `sudo chown root -R filter in /opt/epson-inkjet-printer-201207w/cups/lib` directory.

I don't know why I didn't dig in permissions, because the error says about this.